# How to multiply a column under a certain condition by using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Say I have a Datatable like :

```
Date       |  Qty | Price
20/10/2013 |  3   |  1.25
21/10/2013 |  5   |  1 
22/10/2013 |  2   |  0.75
24/10/2013 |  1   |  0.90
```

I want to multiply by 0.98 the column price if the date is after 22/10/2013 included.

I have already coded something for that , but I would like to do it with linq, do you know how can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output after the processing? DataTable, List?

Comment: A datatable is expected

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is all about querying, not updating. You can use it to query for rows that should be updated, but still have to do that update by yourself, e.g. using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var row in dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= myDateTime))
    row.SetField<double>("Price", row.Field<double>("Price") * 0.98);
```

Comment: Won't SetField modify the original rows?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to update the `DataTable` I see no reason for using LINQ here. Instead, I'd just use the [DataTable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx):

```
var d = new DataTable();
d.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
d.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
d.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(double));
d.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("20/10/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3, 1.25);
d.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("21/10/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 5, 1.0);
d.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("22/10/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 2, 0.75);
d.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("24/10/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 1, 0.90);

foreach (var item in d.Select("Date >= #10/22/2013#"))
{
    item.SetField("Price", item.Field<double>("Price") * 0.98);
}
```

Comment: Just change item[]to item.SetField, item.Field and you're OK :P

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the  [System.Data.DataSetExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx). Then you can  select the relevant rows with Where()  eg.

```
var rows=from row in myTable.AsEnumerable()
         where row.Field<DateTime>("Date")>=new DateTime(2013,10,22(
         select rows;
```

Then you can modify the row values in a loop:

```
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    row["Price"]=0.98m*(decimal)row["Price"];
}
```

or, to avoid the boxing and unboxing operations, you can use [SetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336477%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the DataSetExtensions:

```
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    row.SetField<decimal>("Price",row.Field<decimal>("Price")*0.98m);
}
```

If you don't want to update the original rows but you want to get a new table with the matching rows modified, things get a bit trickier. You would have to clone each DataRow in your `Select` and set the appropriate field if the date criteria matches.

A simpler solution, would be to simply clone the original table with [DataTable.Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) and apply the change to the clone. This won't affect performance as you would copy the original data anyway.

You could do something like this:

```
var myCopy=myTable.Clone();
var rows=from row in myClone.AsEnumerable()
         where row.Field<DateTime>("Date")>=new DateTime(2013,10,22(
         select rows;
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    row.SetField<decimal>("Price",row.Field<decimal>("Price")*0.98m);
}
```

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Nitpicking :P